# Google Cloud Datastore JSON for an Array of Keys

Tags: arrays, json, key, google-cloud-datastore

I tried this JSON at the Google Datastore Console to create a property as an array of keys (one-to-many relationship) but it doesn't work:

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "keyValue": key(user, 1234567890123456)
        },
        {
            "keyValue": key(user, 6544567890123456)
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See JSON format: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/Key

The JSON will be like:

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "keyValue": {
        "path": [
          {
            "kind": "user",
            "id": "1234567890123456"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "keyValue": {
        "path": [
          {
            "kind": "user",
            "id": "6544567890123456"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. After entering the exact JSON code you provided the GC Console gladly accepted it.